# MySQL Find all members not invited

Tags: mysql

I have a members table and then a memberevents table. The memberevents table has a memberid and an eventid. I am trying to find all members who have no record for event 3. It sounds simple to do, but I can't figure it out! I am thinking I should query the memberevents table and group by memberid, and then I think I should so a subquery, but I can't write this query. Can someone please help?

I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT m.memberid 
    FROM memberevents m 
    WHERE m.eventid != 3 
    GROUP BY m.memberid
) t
```

Comment: If you can use sqlfiddle.com to build a demo, we can help you some more. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can express the SQL query almost exactly following the logic that you expressed in English:

```
select *
from members m
where not exists (select 1
                  from memberevents me
                  where me.eventid = 3 and me.memberid = m.memberid
                 );
```